# How to create .cer from apple api json

Tags: ios, xcode, certificate, apple-developer

I need to make automatic for all apple operations:

- create csr (i did in terminal with openssl)
- Create certificate in developer.apple (i used apple api https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreconnectapi/create_a_certificate)
- Need to get certificate detail and i did but i could not download .cer file from returned response. In manually case it can be install from developer.apple.com, so i need to do it dynamic from my software.

Response example: ([GET] https://api.appstoreconnect.apple.com/v1/certificates/{id}
)

```
  "data": {
    "type": "certificates",
    "id": "cert id xxxx",
    "attributes": {
      "serialNumber": "xxxxx",
      "certificateContent": "cer content...",
      "displayName": "xxx",
      "name": "iOS Distribution: xxx",
      "csrContent": null,
      "platform": "IOS",
      "expirationDate": "2020-09-03T20:03:52.000+0000",
      "certificateType": "IOS_DISTRIBUTION"
    },
    "links": {
      "self": "https://api.appstoreconnect.apple.com/v1/certificates/xxx"
    }
  },
  "links": {
    "self": "https://api.appstoreconnect.apple.com/v1/certificates/xxx"
  }
}
```

Apple says you can download with this api and i researched how to create .cer from this data therefore i could not.

**Note**: If decode "certificateContent" i can see my company information.

**Summarize**: I need to create cer from this response and add to keychain with 
this command: `security add-trusted-cert -d -r trustRoot -k /Library/Keychains/System.keychain ios_distribution.cer`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved: base64 --decode certificateContent.txt > certificate.cer

Comment: Did you able to create certificate using AppStoreApi? I have troubles with it, can't understand what is wrong with the request. Could you [have a look the issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61422472)?
thank you in advance!