# Can't create IOS_DISTRIBUTION certificate using AppStore Connect API. Error 409/ENTITY_ERROR.ATTRIBUTE.INVALID/Invalid Certificate

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I'm trying to create a certificate [using **AppStore Connect API**](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreconnectapi/create_a_certificate). For that I created valid *(I used it to fetch certificates list using GET method, it works)* JWT token : `eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJFUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IkZZREszQlVIOE0ifQ.eyJpc3MiOiIwNWNiN2M3Yy00Y2RkLTRlYjMtYWRiZC1kNzkwYWEyYTBhNjEiLCJleHAiOjE1ODc3OTg1MjMuMjI3ODIyLCJhdWQiOiJhcHBzdG9yZWNvbm5lY3QtdjEifQ.Vs1xpLL2xF_WtQNXg3m1XySG-mdSsR2fQalhDgFy5NkIhtRWtWfxkyxMOTe3la-zqWAKjZ7iiCGf8Fkm5_cl2Q`

Pretty printed JSON Http body is:

```
{
  "data":{
    "attributes":{
      "certificateType":"IOS_DISTRIBUTION",
      "csrContent":"'$(cat private.csr | base64)'"
    },
    "type":"certificates"
  }
}
```

where `private.csr` file generated by **Keychain Access** and contains:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----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-----END CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----
```

Next I perform `curl` request:

```
curl -v -X POST  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Authorization: Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJFUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IkZZREszQlVIOE0ifQ.eyJpc3MiOiIwNWNiN2M3Yy00Y2RkLTRlYjMtYWRiZC1kNzkwYWEyYTBhNjEiLCJleHAiOjE1ODc3OTg1MjMuMjI3ODIyLCJhdWQiOiJhcHBzdG9yZWNvbm5lY3QtdjEifQ.Vs1xpLL2xF_WtQNXg3m1XySG-mdSsR2fQalhDgFy5NkIhtRWtWfxkyxMOTe3la-zqWAKjZ7iiCGf8Fkm5_cl2Q' -d '{"data":{"attributes":{"certificateType":"IOS_DISTRIBUTION","csrContent":"'$(cat private.csr | base64)'"},"type":"certificates"}}' https://api.appstoreconnect.apple.com/v1/certificates
```

But server responds the error:

> ```
> < HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
> * We are completely uploaded and fine
> < HTTP/1.1 409 Conflict
> < Server: daiquiri/3.0.0
> < Date: Sat, 25 Apr 2020 07:20:08 GMT
> < Content-Type: */*
> < Content-Length: 254
> < Connection: keep-alive
> < Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate
> < Pragma: no-cache
> < X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
> < X-Frame-Options: ALLOW-FROM https://devcms.apple.com SAMEORIGIN
> < Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
> < X-Request-ID: QRCVNTSDFD6UA4O62U7ZZM67ZM
> < X-Rate-Limit: user-hour-lim:3600;user-hour-rem:3598;
> < x-daiquiri-instance: daiquiri:38493002:pv50p00it-hyhk10063901:7987:20E24
> < 
> {
>   "errors" : [ {
>     "id" : "7470a152-5d89-4d85-8e6e-987754c519c3",
>     "status" : "409",
>     "code" : "ENTITY_ERROR.ATTRIBUTE.INVALID",
>     "title" : "An attribute in the provided entity has invalid value",
>     "detail" : "Invalid Certificate"
>   } ]
> * Connection #0 to host api.appstoreconnect.apple.com left intact
> ```

I already have no idea what is wrong. I checked that there are no limits for iOS Distribution certificates in my account.

Comment: As far as I know there is a distribution certificate limit 4

Comment: @BatuhanAkkaya Nope, there is only 1 distribution certificate in account and I can create more. Anyway I removed existing certificate, and the issue didn't gone

Comment: asked the question at [Apple developer forums] (https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/416711#416711)

Comment: It was working when I tried yesterday. And I cannot see any problem in your code but I am using nodejs.

Comment: Be sure csrContent correct. Also I used this: https://www.thesslstore.com/knowledgebase/ssl-generate/generate-csr-apache-web-server-using-openssl-v-2/

Comment: @BatuhanAkkaya I generated new csr file using `openssl`, but it didn't help. Still the same error.

Comment: @BatuhanAkkaya I found where the issue was :)

Answer (score 1):

After a couple a days I found the issue. It was that I base64 encoded CSR file. Don't need to do it, this file is already contains BASE64 data in between

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----
...
BASE64 ENCODED DATA 
...
-----END CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----
```

So the correct body is

```
{
  "data":{
    "attributes":{
      "certificateType":"IOS_DISTRIBUTION",
      "csrContent":"'$(cat private.csr)'"
    },
    "type":"certificates"
  }
}
```